# Submit button in template leading to HTTP ERROR 405

Tags: django

I am adding a comment section for my posts, the issue is after submitting it leads to  `HTTP ERROR 405`
 This is the first time to receive this error, I have reviewed the views several times but I think the error might be from the views.py in post detail view

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "post_detail.html"

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostDetailView, self).get_context_data()
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=post).order_by('-id')
        total_likes = post.total_likes()
        liked = False
        if post.likes.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
            liked = True

        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            comment_form = CommentForm(self.request.POST or None)
            if comment_form.is_valid():
                content = self.request.POST.get('content')
                comment = Comment.objects.create(
                    post=post, user=request.user, content=content)
                comment.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect("post_detail.html")
        else:
            comment_form = CommentForm()

        context["total_likes"] = total_likes
        context["liked"] = liked
        context["comments"] = comments
        context["comment_form"] = comment_form
        return context
```

here is the template

```
            <form method="post" class="comment-form" action=".">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ comment_form.as_p }}
            {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-outline-success">
            {% else %}
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-outline-success" disabled> You must be Logged in to Comment
            {% endif %}
            </form>
            <div class="main-comment-section">
            {{comments.count}} Comment{{comments|pluralize}}
            {% for comment in comments %}
            <blockquote class="blockquote">
                <p class="mb-0"> {{ comment.content}}</p>
                <footer class="blockquote-footer">by<cite title="Source Title">{{comment.user| capfirst}}</cite></footer>
            </blockquote>
            {% endfor %}
```

here is the comments models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=160)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}-{}'.format(self.post.title, str(self.user.username))
```

Answer (score 0):

doing `POST` request on [DetailView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/) would result in such response as it only implements `get()` method and it is intended to be used only for displaying data

You'll have to step back to understand [class based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/intro/) ( they have methods for each type of request get() post() etc.)

After following you can take step into understanding [generic class based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/)

You probably wanted to use [FormView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#form-handling-with-class-based-views) instead

Answer (score 0):

As i understood you need to refresh the page so the results would show up.
I'd suggest to use `AJAX` call for that.
Aswell, you need to return `context`, not a `http response`.

```
class PostDetail(CsrfExemptMixin, JSONResponseMixin,AjaxResponseMixin):
    def post_ajax(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
                comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
                if comment_form.is_valid():
                    content = request.POST.get('content')
                    comment = Comment.objects.create(
                        post=post, user=request.user, content=content)
                    comment.save()
                                return self.render_json_response({'comment': comment})
```